# Deadlock on read/wait

Tags: pipe, read, ipc, deadlock

My process deadlocks. `master` looks like this:

```
p=Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
for ....: # a few million
    p.stdin.write(...)
p.stdin.close()
out = p.stdout.read()
p.stdout.close()
exitcode = p.wait()
```

`child` looks something like this:

```
l = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
   l.append(line)
sys.stdout.write(str(len(l)))
```

- `strace -p PID_master` shows that `master` is stuck in `wait4(PID_child,...)`.
- `strate -p PID_child` shows that `child` is stuck in `read(0,...)`.

How can that be?! 
**I did `close` the `stdin`, why is `child` still reading from it?!**

Comment: Why shouldn't it still be blocking on `read()`?  You need to post the actual code, not just explain what you *think* it does.

Comment: Agree with goldilocks, almost certainly your script does not do what you think it is does. If your script uses system tools, they may not function as you intend.

Comment: @goldilocks: I expanded the code. Thanks.

Comment: @PSkocik: you mean the master should have a separate thread to write to each child? how would it help?

Comment: @PSkocik: `cmd` starts to write only after the `for l in stdin` finishes. IOW, it is _not_ a filter.

Comment: Could you post something runnable that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @PSkocik: not really; sorry (for one, the master reads a LOT of data from s3) well, I guess I can mock something up...

Comment: @goldilocks: I have [full reproducible code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219951/31443)!

Comment: Um, why is your parent writing to _stdin_ and reading from _stdout_? Or are those just labels without implied correspondence to the real  _stdin_ and _stdout_?

Comment: @roaima: I don't know Python, but he's talking about a parent and a child, and there's a `popen()` function in C that spawns a child process with pipes to and from, so I guess Python's `Popen()` is similar.  So I guess that the parent is writing to *the child's* stdin and reading from *the child's* stdout (via pipes).  (It confused me at first, too.)

Comment: @G-Man, ah, I see. In that case it's a straightforward pipe 4K buffering issue. I'll see if I can find a duplicate for future reference

Comment: @roaima: I don't understand why you would say so.  Apparently `for line in sys.stdin:` / `l.append(line)` means `while read(stdin) returns data (i.e., until EOF), append the data to the “l” (list) data structure`; i.e., the child reads all the data it can, as fast as it can.  According to [the new version of this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219951/80216), the OP's exact code works fine in some versions of Python, but not others, and may (or may not) be a manifestation of [this documented bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue4112).

Comment: @G-Man ok. Suggestion withdrawn. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ["python", "child.py"]
p=Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
for i in range(1,100000):
    p.stdin.write("hello\n")
p.stdin.close()
out = p.stdout.read()
p.stdout.close()
print(out)
exitcode = p.wait()
```

child.py

```
import sys
l = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
   l.append(line)
sys.stdout.write(str(len(l)))
```

Running it:

```
$ python parent.py 
  99999
```

Looks like this works fine so the problem must be somewhere else.